# `eval('bar')` causes a `NameError`, but `print(bar); eval('bar')` doesn't

Tags: python, scope, local-variables, nameerror

The following code

```
1 def foo():
2     def bar():
3         return 'blah'
4     def baz():
5         eval('bar')
6     baz()
7 foo()
```

causes a `NameError` -- the entire error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo()
  File "main.py", line 6, in foo
    baz()
  File "main.py", line 5, in baz
    eval('bar')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

On the other hand, the following, almost identical code,

```
1 def foo():
2     def bar():
3         return 'blah'
4     def baz():
5         print(bar); eval('bar')
6     baz()
7 foo()
```

does not cause any error. In fact, it prints `<function foo.<locals>.bar at 0x7fd5fdb24af0>`.

So I was wondering why, in the first piece of code, is the variable named `bar` not defined/available in line `5`. And why does `print`ing `bar` before calling `eval('bar')` fix this issue. From my understanding `bar` should be a local variable of `function foo`, so it should be accessible from `function foo.baz`. Is it something about `eval` that screws this up that `print`ing beforehand fixes?

Comment: The first function makes sense; `bar` isn't global and it's not local. The second function is interesting. Even though `bar` is not local to `baz` (it's a free variable), its presence seems to be sufficient for `eval` to see it as a local.

Comment: A local variable that's accessed from a nested function has to be stored in an entirely different way than a normal local, to account for the possibility that the nested function could be called after the original function has ended, and its normal locals have ceased to exist.  This different form of storage involves an additional layer of indirection, and is therefore slightly slower than normal variable access - so Python only does it for variables that are clearly accessed by a nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> help(eval)
Help on built-in function eval in module builtins:

eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.
    
    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

In your first example `bar` is not in local scope but in your second example it is in local because the statement `print(bar)` forces a scope resolution lookup before `eval` executes. (In neither example is `bar` in global scope.)

There are a couple of options you can use to pull `bar` into your desired scope:

```py
# option 1: nonlocal (better)
def foo():
    def bar():
        return 'blah'
    def baz():
        nonlocal bar
        eval('bar');
    baz()
foo()

# option 2: pass a copy of actual scope to eval (less better)
def foo():
    def bar():
        return 'blah'
    def baz():
        eval('bar', None, local_scope);  # or eval('bar', local_scope)
    local_scope = locals()
    baz()
foo()
```